# Aiohhtp Web.response Adding headers

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

Here is a method ends,  which despatches matches in body and number of matches in headers.

```
.
. 
match_count = len(matches)
tot = {'total': match_count}
return web.json_response({"matches": fdata}, headers=tot)
```

While processing I am getting below Server error

```
File "/workspace/aio/server/aioenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/http_writer.py", line 111, in write_headers
    buf = _serialize_headers(status_line, headers)
  File "aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx", line 138, in aiohttp._http_writer._serialize_headers
  File "aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx", line 110, in aiohttp._http_writer.to_str
TypeError: Cannot serialize non-str key 19
```

Somebody please explain. tot must be a dict. as docs explain how can I convert this into str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header cannot contain an int value. You have to convert it to a string as follows:

```
tot = {'total': str(match_count)}
```

Comment: @outflak, Though I found it. I upvoted.